# Performance and when data gets loaded in JS Frameworks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I'm relatively new to it. So I have a general question about JS frameworks like React and vue. And to perfomance.

Will all the data be loaded at once in websites using React or vue? For example, if I have a page with many pictures. They are then loaded when the component is used or when the user calls the page?

I have found a [simple example of a vanilla JavaScript spa](https://codingislove.com/implementing-single-page-architecture-with-vanilla-javascript/). There, the pages are only hidden, but still loaded. Is that similar in the big frameworks?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a framework-related question, I am pretty sure you can achieve this behaviour with any JS framework such as React and Angular. I don't know Vue but as long as it's javascript you have control of the DOM tree so you can perform this kind of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the frameworks load the whole codebase and media at once, when you visit a SPA for the first time. You have the whole code and media, you don't have to reload the app each time you navigate through it.

However, some of the frameworks allow you to build your apps using lazy loading. When a SPA is using lazy loading, it loads certain JS and html files only when necessary.

With React, you can build your apps using both techniques. You can force user to load all the coverage at once or divide your files per route.